# gorename failing in VS Code without explicit error

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I am trying to rename a variable using F2. This seems to run the gorename tool, but fails every time without explicit error. It simply displays:

```
/home/oops/dev/mtg-tracker/mtg-tracker-server/handlers>Finished running tool: /home/oops/dev/go/bin/golint

/home/oops/dev/mtg-tracker/mtg-tracker-server/handlers>Finished running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go build -i -o /tmp/vscode-goVw9yJs/go-code-check .

/home/oops/dev/mtg-tracker/mtg-tracker-server/handlers>Finished running tool: /usr/local/go/bin/go vet ./...

Rename failed
```

I've looked into similar issues and it seems to normally come with an error such as an invalid GOROOT or incorrect package naming, but I see no such error here and I haven't been able to find any further info.

I also saw that someone fixed this by updating gorename, which I tried looking into but have not been able to figure out how to do.

Expected result: VSCode actually renames my variable.

Actual result: The rename fails and it stays the same.

Comment: `gopls` has evolved since then. Can you check with the latest gopls 0.2.0? All you need to do is update Go and then the tools associated. (`Go: Install/Update Tools`). I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Note there is an [issue 24661](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24661) dedicated to follow the tools and their updates, for command-line or VSCode usage.

That issue [just included](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24661#issuecomment-529799814):

> `gorename` will no longer be supported as `gopls` already implemented renaming functionality.

See [issue 27571](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27571), which refers to [issue 32875](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32875).

In the meantime, pending full support of `gorename`, I am using [`saibing/tools`](https://github.com/saibing/tools) which does produced an "extended" version of `gopls`, with rename support.
And which is working just fine in VSCode.

---

Update Q4 2019 (Nov.): [issue 32875](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32875) is now closed, [gopls has released a 0.2.0](https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1194056152285351937) and those errors should be fixed.

A full rename support is still there: [CL 194878](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/194878)

Remains [CL 207579](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/207579/): This change adds command line support for `prepare_rename`.

---

Update Sept. 2020:

[As commented](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24661#issuecomment-693598689) and in [CL 255053](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/tools/+/255053/) (for [`go bundle`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle)), a lot of the tools in this list have been replaced by `gopls` as well.